# Как вывести список совпадающих значений через функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Есть список:

```
eject = [-7.1, 4.2, 6.1]
```

Есть датафрейм:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2011, 2032, 2013, 2014],
    'list': [-4.4, 6.1, -5.5, -3.3, -7.1, -3.1, -5.2, 4.2]
})
```

Необходимо из списка с помощью функции def вывести значения:

[2011, 2014, 2018]

Пробовал так, но не работает(:

```
def looc1(duf, doc, listt):
    miine = []
    for i in eject:
        miine.append(duf[listt == i].doc.values[0])
    return miine

looc1(df1, year, df1.list)
```

Хотя без def работает нормально:

```
miine = []

for i in eject(df1.list):
    miine.append(df1[df1.list == i].year.values[0])
print(miine)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код чинится так:

```
def looc1(duf, doc, listt):
    miine = []
    for i in eject:
        miine.append(duf[listt == i][doc].values[0])
    return miine

print(looc1(df1, 'year', df1.list))
```

Но при этом вы не передаёте список `eject` в функцию, а используете его напрямую, что не есть хорошо. И сделать это всё можно гораздо короче:

```
def looc2(df, where, col, eject):
    return df.loc[df[where].isin(eject), col].tolist()

print(looc2(df1, 'list', 'year', eject))
```

Вывод:

```
[2018, 2011, 2014]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

eject = [-7.1, 4.2, 6.1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2011, 2032, 2013, 2014],
    'list': [-4.4, 6.1, -5.5, -3.3, -7.1, -3.1, -5.2, 4.2]
})


def myfunc(df, lst):
    return df[df.loc[:,"list"].isin(lst)]["year"].to_list()

myfunc(df1, eject)
```

результат:

```
[2018, 2011, 2014]
```